# Does Ubuntu One sync files located inside a relocated Home folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, home-directory

It is my understanding that Ubuntu One does not sync files or folders that are not located within the Ubuntu file structure, that is, I cannot sync files on an additional hard disk (please correct me if I"m wrong), but I am wondering, if I were to reinstall Ubuntu and relocate (or mount) my Home folder to another partition (for argument sake, the partition is on another Hard Disk) would Ubuntu One file sync work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu One client will only synchyronise folders located under your home directory.  It doesn't care which file system those folders reside on though.  So if `/home` is a separate file system, it shouldn't matter.

If you had a file system mounted somewhere under your home directory, the client should be able to synchronise that too.

The only thing to keep in mind is that you should ensure that such a partition is always mounted when the Ubuntu One synchronisation daemon is running.  For instance, if a separate file system is mounted at `~/Music` and that folder is synchronised, unmounting that folder might look like all the files under have been deleted.

If the file system is on a fixed disk and mounted through `/etc/fstab`, then there shouldn't be much of a problem.  I would advise against doing this kind of thing with removable media though.